# Create multiple VMware guests with vsphere_guest module

Tags: vmware-vsphere, ansible

I have the following Ansible playbook for creating (cloning) VMware virtual machines (VMs) from a template:

```
- name: Create VMware guest
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False

  vars_prompt:
    - name: "vcenter"
      prompt: "vCenter hostname?"
      default: "vcenter01.example.com"
    - name: "user"
      prompt: "Enter username"
      private: no
    - name: "pass"
      prompt: "Enter password"
      private: yes
    - name: "template"
      prompt: "Template?"
      default: "linux-template.example.com_deb8"
    - name: "cluster"
      prompt: "Cluster?"
      default: "cl03"
    - name: "resource_pool"
      prompt: "Resource pool?"
      default: "/Resources/IT/IT Department/Linux Systems Team"

  tasks:
  - name: Make sure we have pip
    become: true
    apt: pkg=python-pip state=latest
  - name: Install Python modules
    become: true
    pip: name={{ item }} state=latest
    with_items:
      - pysphere
      - pyvmomi
  - name: Deploy guest from template
    vsphere_guest:
      vcenter_hostname: "{{ vcenter }}"
      username: "{{ user }}"
      password: "{{ pass }}"
      guest: "{{ guest }}"
      from_template: yes
      template_src: "{{ template }}"
      cluster: "{{ cluster }}"
      resource_pool: "{{ resource_pool }}"
```

I invoke it like this:

```
ansible-playbook createvm.yml --ask-become-pass -e guest=<guest-name>
```

How could I create multiple VMs without running the playbook multiple times, i.e. answering all the prompt questions? The only variable that gets changed it VM's name (`guest`). I'd like something like this:

```
ansible-playbook createvm.yml --ask-become-pass -e guest=server1,server3,server3
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write a `with_items` loop for the guest parameter as well. Like this:

```
- name: Deploy guest from template
  vsphere_guest:
    vcenter_hostname: "{{ vcenter }}"
    username: "{{ user }}"
    password: "{{ pass }}"
    guest: "{{ item }}"
    from_template: yes
    template_src: "{{ template }}"
    cluster: "{{ cluster }}"
    resource_pool: "{{ resource_pool }}"
   with_items: "{{ serverlist }}"
```

If you don't want to hard code the variables in the play (which is not a bad idea) you can store the list in a variable and put this under `host_vars/hostname` like this:

```
---
serverlist:
  - server1
  - server2
```

Ansible has `vault` included for storing passwords and sensitive information. Take a look at the [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_vault.html) for more information.

You can create an variable file encrypted with vault and include this in your play with

```
- include_vars: vault.yml
```

Comment: How would I supply the variables for the `with_items` (server1, server2, server3)? I don't want them hard-coded into the playbook.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution that seems to be working fine - using environment variables. I replaced the `vars_prompt` section of the playbook with:

```
  vars:
    vcenter: "{{ lookup('env','ANS_VCENTER') }}"
    cluster: "{{ lookup('env','ANS_CLUSTER') }}"
    template: "{{ lookup('env','ANS_TEMPLATE') }}"
    resource_pool: "{{ lookup('env','ANS_RESOURCE_POOL') }}"
    user: "{{ lookup('env','ANS_USER') }}"
    password: "{{ lookup('env','ANS_PASS') }}"
```

I set the environment variables before running the playbook, like

```
export ANS_VCENTER="vcenter01.example.com"
```

(I was a bit concerned storing password in an environment variable but it seems to be [secure enough](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14000/environment-variable-accessibility-in-linux)).

Then I can create multiple guests using a shell for loop

```
for g in server1 server2 server3; do echo "--> Create $g"; ansible-playbook createvm.yml -e guest=$g; done
```